# Formula to use to achieve the header into each row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to convert some data in my Google sheet. Attached is the screenshot on how I currently have the data and how I am looking to format the data into.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

assuming your data starts in cell Sheet1!A2 and extends indefinitely down and indefinitely over, try this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(Sheet1!A3:A&" "&Sheet1!B2:2&"|"&OFFSET(Sheet1!B3,,,9^9,9^9)),"|",0,0),"where Col2 is not null",0))
```

Comment: This ignited some *great* ideas, but it doesn't really what the question was asking for work. You might want to pull it down.

Comment: @pgSystemTester I don't really understand.  I think my answer provides the exact solution that was being looked for?  I will update it to have indefinite ranges if you think that's helpful.

Comment: I did notice that I didn't properly test your first solution as I didn't line up the data properly with `A2` vs `A1` (your presumption makes sense based on the original graphic -- my fault). However that produced three columns. I can't get your revised solution to work. Checkout the shared file I posted and feel free to edit or add a tab. I'm curious about your offset approach. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pP7lVekF5fcjEpzUkD_OqmBAVMP4DNvyAH2fX7gFE1g/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I seem to have missed a closing parenthesis in my example formula.  I fixed it in your sheet and edited my solution above.

Comment: Confirmed! Nice. I upvoted. I'm glad I checked, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

Derived from MattKing's answer, I've added `transpose` in conjunction with some manipulation on the concatenation part to follow the type of sorting your **Required Data Format** had. This should give you the same output you provided above.

#### Sample Data:

[image: sample]

#### Formula:

```
=arrayformula(split(flatten(transpose(A2:A6&" "&B1:D1)&"|"&transpose(B2:D6)),"|"))
```

Where:

- `A2:A6` is the range of your project names
- `B1:D1` is the range of your headers
- `B2:D6` is the range of your dates

#### Result:

[image: result]

#### EDIT:

If you are expecting blank cells in your dates such as the sample below (as pgSystemTester mentioned in the comments section):

[image: sample]

You need to add `query` and exclude those rows that doesn't have dates.

```
=arrayformula(query({split(flatten(transpose(A2:A6&" "&B1:D1)&"|"&transpose(B2:D6)),"|")}, "where Col2 is not null"))
```

[image: output]

Comment: That's cool. I was looking for something like that. Can you account for a dynamic range that excludes blank cells? That's the only advantage my solution might have over yours. Thanks for posting.

Comment: Hi @pgSystemTester, I could definitely add a query on that same as what MattKing did provide. Let me test it and update my answer.

Comment: @pgSystemTester, adding query works. see updated answer above.

Comment: I'll have to think of a way for providing an answer that expects a dynamic range.

Comment: I think your example for missing milestones would be to the right, not left but not a big deal. Still a solid answer... any time custom functions can be avoided, that's a good think. Upvoting!

Comment: Thanks @pgSystemTester, regarding the dynamic range, I think it would be hard to provide given the formula above, it might need a different approach to do it. But definitely, it would be much easier if OP would consider the custom formula you provided if it comes to that.

Comment: Also, my question was for blank headers, not blank dates. Our answers perform the same with blank dates, although I could easily adjust. Like I said the only advantage I might see over yours is that OP could put a custom formula of like `=buildTwoColumnsData(a:z)` and just leave it like that as data came in or got deleted.

Comment: Here is the de facto answer solution that we were looking for. See my answer for where I stole it from: `=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(B2:E="",,A2:A&" "&B1:E1&"×"&B2:E)), "×"), 
 "where Col2 is not null"))`

Comment: OFFSET is the best way to have a 2d dynamic range (imo)  you use the vertex of the range as an anchor, then 9^9 for the height and width:
=OFFSET(B2,,,9^9,9^9)

Comment: @MattKing I hate offset, but I can tell you're no slouch, so I'm curious how that could work. Mind posting on this sheet to illustrate? I think Player() has conquered all of us with the best answer, but I am still getting used to arrays/spill stuff. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pP7lVekF5fcjEpzUkD_OqmBAVMP4DNvyAH2fX7gFE1g/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Just to give another option, and spurred on by this (likely repeat) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68766814/excel-combine-row-column-content-and-find-respecting-value/68766971#68766971)

```
=LET(x, $I$2:$L$4,
myrows, ROWS(x),
mycols, COLUMNS(x),
mycount, SEQUENCE(myrows*mycols),
car, $H$2:$H$4, color, $I$1:$L$1,
mylist, car&" "&color,
mycolumn, INDEX(mylist, CEILING(mycount/mycols,1), IF(MOD(mycount,mycols)=0, mycols,MOD(mycount,mycols))),
mydata, INDEX(x, CEILING(mycount/mycols,1), IF(MOD(mycount,mycols)=0, mycols,MOD(mycount,mycols))),
IF(SEQUENCE(1,2)=1, mycolumn, mydata))
```

[image]

Comment: Yep. But sheets will have it soon I am guessing. So weird these two questions came out so close together... these peeps are probably in some class together and we're doing their homework! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can [see a sample sheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pP7lVekF5fcjEpzUkD_OqmBAVMP4DNvyAH2fX7gFE1g/edit?usp=sharing), with several of answers illustrated on each tab.

### Formula With No App Scripts

This is an update and includes a formula that was stolen from [a different answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68767690/11732320) that appears to nail it. ([Player()](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5632629/player0) is officially the Jack Bauer of Spreadsheets... don't ask how he gets things done!).

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(B2:E="",,A2:A&" "&B1:E1&"×"&B2:E)), "×"), 
 "where Col2 is not null"))
```

Make sure this is placed off to the right so that it doesn't spill into itself.

### My Original App Scripts Solution

This is honestly not needed any more, but I worked on it for half an hour and maybe someone might find it helpful if they have trouble sleeping.

```
/**
 * Creates 2 Columns of Data
 *
 * @param {range} theRangeValues The Table Range.
 * @return The two columns of data with all combinations based on rows and columns
 * @customfunction
 */
function buildTwoColumnsData(theRangeValues) {
  var allValues = [];
  var i = 1;
  var cCell = theRangeValues[0][i];
  while (cCell != '' && i < theRangeValues[0].length) {
    var theEnd = cCell;
    var g = 1;
    var rCell = theRangeValues[g][0];
    while (rCell != '' && g < theRangeValues.length) {
      allValues.push([rCell + " " + theEnd, theRangeValues[g][i]])
      g++;
      if (g < theRangeValues.length) {
        rCell = theRangeValues[g][0];
      }
    }
    i++;
    if (i < theRangeValues[0].length) {
      cCell = theRangeValues[0][i];
    }
  }
  return allValues;
}
```