# Excel/Sheets combine row column content and find respecting value

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, split, flatten, google-query-language

**Sheet1**

I have this data of car price based on its color on Sheet1

| Car | Red | Blue | Black | White |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BMW | 100 | 120 | 90 | 120 |
| FIAT | 90 | 100 | 110 | 120 |
| FORD | 70 | 80 | 80 | 80 |

**Sheet2**

I want these cars and colors combined in column A. In column B, I want to display its respective price.
I have achieved to display column A with this formula, but I am open to it if there is any suggestion. For column B, I can not figure out yet how to accomplish the goal.

The formula for column A

```
=ArrayFormula(transpose(split(rept(concatenate(Sheet1!A2:A&char(9)),counta(Sheet1!B1:Sheet1!E1)),char(9)))
&" "&transpose(split(concatenate(rept(Sheet1!B1:Sheet1!E1&char(9),counta(Sheet1!A2:Sheet1!A))),char(9))))
```

I got this formula from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42805885/generate-all-possible-combinations-for-columns-in-google-spreadsheets)

**The expected output in Sheet2**

| Car Color | Price |
| --- | --- |
| BMW Red | 100 |
| BMW Blue | 120 |
| BMW Black | 90 |
| BMW White | 120 |
| FIAT Red | 90 |
| FIAT Blue | 100 |
| FIAT Black | 110 |
| FIAT White | 120 |
| FORD Red | 70 |
| FORD Blue | 80 |
| FORD Black | 80 |
| FORD White | 80 |

Comment: Almost a near identical question like this was asked today. See answer here then suggest you close: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68762676/formula-to-use-to-achieve-the-header-into-each-row/68763695?noredirect=1#comment121525260_68763695

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Since my Google Workspace doesn't support script editing, I will consider this solution for another condition. But for now, I need a solution that is applicable anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(B2:E="",,A2:A&" "&B1:E1&"×"&B2:E)), "×"), 
 "where Col2 is not null"))
```

[image]

Comment: Sorcery!! I added this to my answer in the near identical question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68762676/formula-to-use-to-achieve-the-header-into-each-row/68763695?noredirect=1#comment121525260_68763695

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @pgSystemTester in the comments that you might consider closing this question.

But here is a solution using `LET`, if you have the newest version of Excel.

```
=LET(x, $I$2:$L$4,
myrows, ROWS(x),
mycols, COLUMNS(x),
mycount, SEQUENCE(myrows*mycols),
car, $H$2:$H$4, color, $I$1:$L$1,
mylist, car&" "&color,
mycolumn, INDEX(mylist, CEILING(mycount/mycols,1), IF(MOD(mycount,mycols)=0, mycols,MOD(mycount,mycols))),
mydata, INDEX(x, CEILING(mycount/mycols,1), IF(MOD(mycount,mycols)=0, mycols,MOD(mycount,mycols))),
IF(SEQUENCE(1,2)=1, mycolumn, mydata))
```

[image]

Comment: There is no LET function in Google Sheets, by the way. But this solution is constructive if I use Microsoft Excel.